# Rails and Heroku: How to add records to database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, model-view-controller

I am new rails. I've developed a new app which shows image logos and my database contain url for these images-

In my local development environment I've added records into the database manually. My migration file for creation table looks like as follows-

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :author
      t.string :category
      t.text :description
      t.text :logo_url
      t.string :pdf_file_url

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

Controller-

```
def get_all_books
  # @books = Book.find(2);
  @books = Book.where(:id => 1..3)
  logger.debug(@books.inspect)
  render :json => @books
end
```

My question is there any other way to add records to my books table?

And when I deploy my app to heroku how to add these records to heroku also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a migration file to add columns to your table, for instance if you want to add the amount of pages to the book as integer you can do this:

```
rails generate migration AddPagesToBooks pages:integer
```

and then run `rake db:migrate` or `rails db:migrate` (on rails 5+)

And to add them to your Heroku application you can use `heroku run rake db:migrate`

**EDIT**

If you want to add records to your database you can use your `db/seeds.rb` file

**In there you can do something like this:**

```
100.times do |i|
  Book.create!(title: "book ##{i}", author: "Author ##{i}.",
              category: "category ##{i}", description: "description ##{i}",          
              logo_url: "/logo/logo##{i}", pdf_file_url: "/pdf/file##{i}")
```

And then run `rails db:seed` or `rake db:seed`

This will create 100 records of book with `##{i}` being numbers 1-100.

You can also check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtyT9Sx_Dv4) video to get a better understanding.

Comment: how It will add records? I want to add more than 100 records. Is there any there any other way?